# Unable to install packages for .NETFramework versions that should work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I'm running into an issue where I cannot install NuGet packages, or update packages, even though I have been able to install those packages in the past.

With a clean solution, I can create an ASP.NET MVC project using .NETFramework 4.5.2 (I've also tried with 4.6.1).

Since I take the default authentication options (Individual User Accounts), the Microsoft Owin packages are all scaffolded in, including the core Owin package (which is a dependency of the Microsoft Owin packages).

If I add another project (I started with a basic Class Library, but for testing purposes also tried a MVC project without authentication), I cannot add any Owin-related packages, as the Owin 1.0.0 package fails:

```
PM> Install-Package Owin 

Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Owin.1.0.0' with respect to project 'Core', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'

Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Owin.1.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'

Resolving actions to install package 'Owin.1.0.0'

Resolved actions to install package 'Owin.1.0.0' 

Install failed. Rolling back... 

Package 'Owin.1.0.0 : ' does not exist in project 'Core'
 Install-Package : Could not install package 'Owin 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly referen ces or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author. 
At line:1 char:16
    + Install-Package <<<<  Owin
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand PM>
```

The scaffolded project is using .NetFramework 4.5.2, and already has Owin version 1.0.0 working without a problem.

Similarly, Respond is included by default.  The default version is 1.2.0.

I can use NuGet Package Manager to upgrade to version 1.4.1 without a problem.  But if I try to upgrade to the latest stable, 1.4.2., I get the exact same errors as I do for the Owin install.

A coworker has a copy of the same project via source control, and he is also running VS2015.  He can update to Respond 1.4.2. without a problem.

Another coworker duplicated every test I tried without running into any issues.

Even odder, I was able to add Owin and its dependencies to a .NET Class Library project this morning (but I couldn't upgrade to the newest Respond release).  But after deleting the solution, and starting a new one, I started encountering my problems with a variety of packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the solution.

I tried [flushing my user cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx) and even uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio (deleting any AppData files that seemed related), but the problem persisted.

However, clearing the data in `C:\Users\<<UserName>>\.nuget\packages` has resolved the issue.

Comment: nuGet has gotten so bad recently